# Custom Icon Markers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a library of .bmp logos that I would like to use to symbolize points in QGIS. Does QGIS only support .svg logos?

Comment: You can insert pngs into svg symbols, see http://snorf.net/blog/2014/02/27/embedding-pngs-in-svg-markers-in-qgis/

Comment: Also, bmp are normally huge files, you will definetly better served with PNG